# regex and bigrams

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of bigrams :

> ['only wish', 'please fix', 'please add', 'only request', 'just hope']

and a list of strings:

> ['this is a wonderful utility. My **only wish** is to get a new sync
>   feature.', 'Does not work well, **please fix** the problem.', 'Great,
>   works fine. **just hope** they keep adding new utilities.', 'My **only
>   request** is they add a new ui']

I need to search for these bigrams in the list of strings (assuming I can handle the upper/lower case), I am not sure if regexes are the best way to look up these bigrams in the list of strings, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do the bigrams contain any punctuation? So do you expect 'please fix' to also match 'please, fix'?

Comment: not sensitive to punctuation

Answer (score 2):

Heres one way to do it without regex:

```
bigrams = ['only wish', 'please fix', 'please add', 'only request', 'just hope']
text = ['this is a wonderful utility. My only wish is to get a new sync feature.', 'Does not work well, please fix the problem.', 'Great, works fine. just hope they keep adding new utilities.', 'My only request is they add a new ui']

for string in text:
    for bigram in bigrams:
        if bigram in string.lower():
            print bigram + ' in ' + string
```